# How are "yes" and "no" formatted in sentences?

Tags: punctuation, quotes

If I am expecting an answer from a question and wish to state my prediction, do I need to use quotes around a simple "yes" or "no"?

> I think the answer is no. / I think the answer is "no."
>
> That would be a yes. / That would be a "yes."

Potential end cases:

> Why would he say, "No"?
>
> The votes are in; three yeses and four nos.
>
> The options are yes or no; not "maybe."

Comment: Good question. I myself would say "The answer is no." But let's see what others say.

Comment: @Robusto: That is what I _want_ the answer to be... but mostly just for brevity. I hate wrapping one small word in quotes.

Comment: @MrHen: That is exactly why most people agree with you and leave out the quotation marks, or so I believe. I'd leave them out in most contexts. Perhaps I'd add them if I wanted to emphasize that I was indeed quoting someone.

Comment: @MrHen: Oh, if that's what you *want* it to be, I'd have to say the answer must be no. If you hadn't expressed a preference we could have allowed it, but I'm afraid now you're just S.O.L. =) Seriously, unless you're writing under the constraints of a style guide that specifically mentions this use case, I'd say do as you like. **Nobody** is going to trip over it.

Comment: @Robusto: Heh. I find it worth looking at what other people/styles do. My personal preferences don't always mesh with the rest of the world's use of English. (Especially when it comes to punctuation.)

Comment: @MrHen: one picky, slightly irrelevant thing: I believe the plural of "no" is "noes".

Comment: @Rhodri: Ah, thank you. Do you know about "yeses" or "yesses"?

Comment: @MrHen: Wiktionary claims "yeses".  I'll check Chambers when I get home.

Comment: @MrHen: Chambers, it say "yes(s)es".  So either goes, though for no good reason at all I prefer the single 's' version.

Comment: @OC: I don't understand your original question - as it stands, "I'm expecting the answer 'No,' , or "I'm expecting that the answer will be no," would seem more logical.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unless there's a style guide telling you otherwise, I'd suggest basing your decision on whether you mean the literal words 'yes' and 'no', or the general nature of the response.  Consider:

> Why would he say, "No"?  *(For that is the word that he said.)*

vs

> Why would he say no?  *(What he actually said was "Over my dead body", but let's not worry about that detail.)*

Comment: +1 Precisely. Use quotation marks to quote; if not, don't.

Comment: Works for me. This is pretty close to what I would have guessed.

Comment: The common trends to use quote-like structures in report structures, and drop commas around quotes, are not liked by some people.


He said "Hello" to the children.

He said hello to the children. His answer was "No." His answer was no.

Comment: Still, I can't see that someone could ever say: Why would he say, "No"?

Answer (score 6):

In both *the answer is no* and *say no*, quotes are relatively uncommon. The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) gives these results:

```
the answer is no        484 hits
the answer is " no       27 hits (including punctuation variants)

[say] no               8891 hits
[say] " no "            521 hits (including punctuation variants)
```

However there are only 10 `yesses` and 30 `yeses`, so you might want to reword that one (perhaps *The votes are in: 3 in favor and 4 against*).

My subjective impression is that it is better style to omit the quotes. Your style, of course, is up to you.

Comment: Good note on the "yesses" and "yeses". My instinct is to use the double-s but I apparently am not consistent about it. :P

Comment: @Jason Orendorff, did you include italics as a punctuation variant? If so, could you fill me in on how to search for italics in the Corpus of Contemporary American English? Just curious...

Answer (score 1):

Personal opinion? Put the quotes. This is what they’re there for: to distinguish between the meaning of the word, and the word itself ([“ceci n’est pas une pipe”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images)).

For comparison, consider

> The answer is affirmative.

Here, “affirmative” is a word that signifies that the answer is positive / “yes”. But the word “yes” itself is *not* synonymous with “affirmative” in this usage. I may *affirm* an answer by saying “yes”. But I cannot *yes* an answer to affirm it.

But unfortunately popular writing usually seems to oppose my conviction. That is, in most novels such short expressions are rarely put between quotes even though they are a fragment of  direct speech.

Comment: I'm trying to capture a vague thought flitting around in my head: what about the article? "His answer was a yes." That's not quite the same as "His answer was 'yes'." Or is it?

Comment: @Reg I don’t think that there is a tangible difference with regards to quoting. Logically, this would mean that (at least in this instance, “a yes” is equivalent to “affirmative” … but really we are using in article “a” to refer to the word (as a stand in for an answer) “yes”). But as I’ve said I’m in the minority here.

Answer (score 1):

A handbook of style will tell you that the simpler, cleaner format is usually better, and is becoming more universally accepted.

My instinct would be that you would only want to use quotes if you want to make it explicitly clear that you are quoting an exact, phonetic utterance. Notice the two elements of the criterion:

1. You are quoting a phonetic utterance.
2. You want to make it very clear that you are.

Otherwise, just say no to quotes.

Comment: ELU prizes answers that are supported by linked and attributed references. Answers of the form "The dictionary says ..." are unconvincing, often biased, and sometimes erroneous. Can you please endorse your claim by adding at least one supporting quote (a blockquote would be better formatting than inverted commas here).

Answer (score 0):

- "Answer was 'no'." — correct; gives clean sense.
- "Answer was no." — incorrect; meaning unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure what your above answers are answers _to_. If they are answers to a question, then by your judgement, any instance of reported speech, where the reported content is a paraphrase of the original quote and may be more or less accurate, might be termed incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from [Grammar Girl](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/direct-and-indirect-quotations) (emphasis added),

- "If you are *directly* quoting someone, put the word in quotation marks."
- "If you are *indirectly* quoting someone, don't put the word in quotation marks."

Here are some examples:

- The cat smiled and said, "Yes."
- "No," I replied, "he is unavailable."
- I hoped the answer would be yes, she could go.
- In so many words, I had to tell him no.

In the last two examples, the words "yes" and "no" summarize the nature of the response, but do not necessarily reflect any spoken words.

Comment: << I hoped the answer would be yes >> gives rise to a problem.