# He nodded his head yes; she shook her head no

Tags: gestures

Here I am editing this book I am trying to get ready for publication.  I am running into a number of places where I've got nodding and shaking of the head in response to questions.  The original author writes:

- "I nodded my head yes."
- "...she shook her head no..."

I am also seeing occasional "shake...yes" and "nod...no".

I'm reasonably certain that one shakes one's head for "No" and nods for "Yes".  But how do you write it?

- I nodded my head "Yes." - I shook my head "No."
- I nodded my head yes. - I shook my head no.
- I nodded my head "yes." - I shook my head "yes."

**Or should the "Yes" or "No" even be included in the sentence, since the gesture substitutes for the affirmative or negative?**  If "Yes" or "No" *does* have a place there, how would it be best formatted?

EDITED TO ADD: I've edited this to make it clear that it is not merely a formatting issue with regard to "Yes" or "No".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you're in the UK so must be up and about right now (it's midnight here where I am), so could you give me a quick opinion on this?  Ta.

Comment: "I nodded in agreement" and **"I nodded, yes"**. "I shook my head in disagreement" and **"I shook my head"** which already implies *no*, doesn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are "yes" and "no" formatted in sentences?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21616/how-are-yes-and-no-formatted-in-sentences)

Comment: Personally I'd go for shortening it to "I nodded" and "I shook my head" as often as possible.

Comment: NOT a possible dupe with formatting "yes" or "no".  That is only part of the question, and only if "yes" or "no" should even be included.

Comment: Was the book written in a culture other than your own? The head gestures for yes and no are inverted in a surprisingly large number of countries.

Comment: The author is German-born, but now a US citizen.  So, no, not really a different culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say:

> I nodded my head yes.

is the correct one. Because you're *just* nodding your head and *that's it*. Meanwhile, if you write it like this:

> I nodded my head, "Yes."

That means that you're not only nodding your head, but also literally ***saying*** the word "yes".

Answer (score 3):

In 'An historical syntax of the English language', F T Visser writes:

> ... the fashion which set in in later Modern English – especially in
>   novels – of treating verbs expressing human and animal sounds (such
>   as *bellow*, *coo* and *groan*) as well as such verbs as *smirk*,
>   *smile* and *persist* as if they were [near-] synonyms of *say* [, ie using them as quote verbs] ...

'She nodded "Yes" ' certainly fits in with this trend, and 'She nodded her head "Yes" ' shouldn't be too worrying an extension.

However, with the vastly increased number of 'allowable' quote verbs has come a blurring of the distinction between quote and report structures:

> She said "Merry Christmas!" to him.
>
> She wished him "Merry Christmas!"
>
> She wished him a merry Christmas.
>
> She wished him merry Christmas / a long life / good health.
>
> He smiled ‘hello,’ and we talked as he waited to give his respects.
>   [internet]
>
> When I called out, he smiled hello ... [internet]

'She nodded [her head] yes' may even be acceptable as a report structure (audible words) (cf 'She smiled yes') as well as in the 'She nodded her head in agreement' sense.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! As it turns out, the book in question has now been published, so this is now theoretical.  See *Yesterday's Sandhills* - http://www.prospectavenuebooks.com/

Comment: Sorry I missed the post first time round. Posts resurface, and they're often valuable and/or interesting. // If you're editing what becomes a best-seller, you can go some way towards dictating acceptable usage.

Answer (score 2):

*I am also seeing occasional "shake...yes" and "nod...no"....
I'm reasonably certain that one shakes one's head for "No" and nods for "Yes"*

This is not a correct assumption generally, as became quite clear to me personally when I spoke to certain Indians who indicate "yes" or "go on" or "[emphasis]" by 'shaking' their head left to right to left in the plane of the body.

See these articles:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_bobble
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nod_(gesture)

Could it be that your text is trying to explicitly mark such cultural differences?

If not, and a typical Western context can be assumed, I'm pretty indifferent between "I nodded my head yes." and "I shook my head no."  I would compare it to the difference between "I shrugged." and "I shrugged my shoulders" (although I suppose one can shrug off a burden, but that's a different thought).

Comment: The text was originally written in English by a native German-speaker who is a long-time resident and citizen of the USA.  German culture as to head nod/shake is identical to Anglo so far as I know.